# Inline PHP in HTML fetch_assoc error

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating an online dictionary, now I have two files index.php and search.php
The index.php contains the HTML stuff like the form etc. and search.php file contains the db connection and the query.
Now I would like to show the tables like:

```
ATranslation BTranslation
wordA         wordB
```

I am trying to realze it with inline php:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
// Include the search class
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/search.php' );
...
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

....
<?php if($query->num_rows > 0) : ?>
// output data of each row

    <?php while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
        <?php echo "<tr>";?>
        <?php foreach ( $row as $value ) : ?>
            <?php echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php echo "</tr>";?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php echo "0 results";?>

<?php endif; ?>
....
                                         index.php
```

but the $query looks like :

```
...
public function search($search_term) {
// prevent injection attacks

$sanitized = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($search_term);
$keyword = $_GET['s'];

// Run the query
$query = $this->mysqli->query("
  SELECT word_p
  FROM tpo
  WHERE word_p LIKE '%{$keyword}%'
  OR word_t LIKE '%{$keyword}%'

");
 ....
                                        search.php
```

and is in the search.php file

I get an error fetch_assoc error or a no results

Comment: Have you executed the same query with phpMyAdmin ? were you able to get any results?

Comment: @SomeOne Yes the query is correct

Comment: @SomeOne i have  recognized that I can't get the $query in index.php the autocomplete of my editor do not offer it

Comment: OK, so here is the problem,  so your query is basically executing inside search method, so, in you index.php, you'll need to do something like:
``` $search = new Search(); $query = $search->search() ```, depending upon what all is required by your search class, you'll need to pass the params to search class when instantiating __Search__. Your search method too needs to return the query object, so that you can use it in __index.php__

Comment: @SomeOne do you mean that I have to fetch object with a loop

Comment: Not exactly, but, __$query__ is not accessible in your index.php, because it's in function scope of search method inside the class that you have. so, if it's not returning $query, you won't be able to use it in your __index.php__

Comment: @SomeOne hmm now I get no results

Comment: hmm, so no result and no error?